# Website Redirect on IIS

Tags: apache, redirect, iis

On Apache Server, we can do the website redirect by placing `.htaccess` file on the root folder with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Is it possible to do it with the same way (placing file on root folder to do redirect) on IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would add a web.config file in place of the .htaccess file.

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="RedirectRule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newdomain.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

More info here: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite